# Javascript to load a link depending on toggle setting in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a JQM with a flip toggle switch.
When the form is submitted I would like JQM to load a page depending on the setting of the toggle.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

```
//bind event handler to the form for the `submit` event
$('form').bind('submit', function () {

    //cache the form element for use later
    var $form = $(this);

    //show loading message
    $.mobile.showLoadingMsg();

    //create an AJAX request using the form's attributes as settings
    $.ajax({
        url     : $form.attr('action'),
        type    : $form.attr('method'),
        data    : $form.serialize(),//this serializes the form's data for transmission
        success : function (serverResponse) {

            //now hide the loading message because the AJAX call is done
            $.mobile.hideLoadingMsg();

            //and redirect the user to the specified page,
            //I am just forwarding the user to the value of the toggle
            //but you can create an if/then statement that directs the user to the proper page
            $.mobile.changePage($('#' + $form.find('.ui-slider-switch').val()));
        }
    });

    //return false to stop the default submission of the form
    return false;
});
```

You will also need to disable the automatic AJAX handling of the form, you can do this by adding `data-ajax="false"` to the `form` tag:

```
<form action="..." data-ajax="false" method="...">
```